# How to communicate RFID tags with IDBlue RFID pen using iPhone?

Tags: iphone, tags, bluetooth, rfid

For iphone is it possible to communicate RFID tags with IDBlue RFID pen (bluetooth connected) and store data into my application?

If yes then is there any some readymade component or code library available for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest IDBLUE.HF reader is compatible with iOS devices. For information on how to develop applications for the reader with iOS, please contact us at http://idblue.com/support/contact-support.

Answer (score 1):

IDBlue has a iOS Framework available here: [IDBlue Framework](http://idblue.com/support/drivers-software). 
(Look under "Developer Toolkits")

The latest version (1.0.0.1) was released 1/12/2012.
It works for their HF and UHF readers, from what I understand.
To add it into your iOS project:

1. Right-click your "Frameworks" folder in the Project Navigator.
2. Select "Add Files to [your project name]..."
3. Navigate to the unzipped sdk folder, "IDBlue.framework".
4. Select this folder

To learn how to use it for development, just use the "help.html" file they've included.
It has fairly detailed documentation on everything.
*Note: In order to integrate the Framework correctly I had to do the following:

1. Add a reference in my Build Phases to Apple's ExternalAccessory framework
2. Set the "Build Active Architecture Only" setting in Build Settings to "Yes"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate with the iPone this device needs to be an MFi compliant device, I don think it is - so the answer is no